# Does Azure Managed Identities only work with Azure VM's?

Tags: azure

I am trying to use a managed identity from Azure in a non-Azure VM to access my Azure resources. Is this possible?

Comment: sure it is.  You simply need to create an api application using any language (I use python and Microsoft's azure python sdk at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/azure-sdk-overview , create the appropriate credentials..

Answer (score 0):

You can use managed identities with App Service too

Answer (score 0):

In the below link you can see all azure resources supported managed identities.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/services-support-managed-identities